# Touch move from one view to another in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can i touch move from one view(Imageview/any layout) to another without lifting the finger from the screen for triggering the touch listener of the 2nd view, just like Pinterest menu or Facebook reaction selection view?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: what you are looking for seems to be drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, it sounds like you need to implement a ViewPager component which will allow you to navigate various views seamlessly.

You can read about it here on the Android developer page: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry i think u have misunderstood the question. I was not asking about ViewPager. 
The context is that if i have a screen with multiple images, and i move my finger over each image, i shud highlight the Imageview in wich my finger is placed above.. all this are done without lifting my finder.. 
for each Imageview i have different functionalities.